# Reset_Index() function acts different for name argument

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 2 lines of code which perform the same thing,

Code1:

df = df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == 1].groupby(['ColumnB'])['ColumnC'].mean().reset_index(name='Avg_ColumnC')

Output Columns:

ColumnB| Avg_ColumnC

Code2:

df = df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == 1].groupby(['ColumnB'])['ColumnC'].mean().reset_index(name='Avg_ColumnC')

But when I run the second line it gives me the error:
TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

The code runs fine if I don't provide the name argument and the results are the same, only thing is name is returned as ColumnC

Comment: mean probabily return None, check how 'mean()' as returning

Comment: The output is exactly the same for both if I don't use the reset_index() function. I just wanted to convert it to a df and change the name of the avg column

Comment: are u running the same code two times?

Comment: I am trying to learn Pandas, was checking on different ways to do the same task.